# Get the biggest value in list object

Tags: list, flutter, dart

How to get the biggest value in list of object?
I want compare the case number

```
print(_abcBloc.vpStream.value);

 _abcBloc.vpStream.value
                .sort((a, b) => a['caseNumber'].compareTo(b['caseNumber']));

 print(_abcBloc.vpStream.value.last['caseNumber']);
```

**Error**

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(ABC, ABC) => int' of 'compare'
```

This is `_abcBloc.vpStream.value` output :

```
[ABC(priority: null,caseNumber: 1,....), ABC(priority: null, caseNumber:2,...)]
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly writing the parameters' types? Example: `(ABC a, ABC b) => a['caseNumber'].compareTo(b['caseNumber'])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, simply write the type of the parameters in the lambda as `(ABC a, ABC b)` to tell the Dart compiler about the types of the lambda. Without the types, the Dart compiler assumes they are `dynamic`, which raises the issue you are facing.

Edit: as the other answers noted, you shouldn't use a `sort` call as it is less effecient (O(nlogn)) than it needs to be (O(n)). Thus, while what I said works, it would be better to use a reduce call.

Answer (score 1):

I also want to add that you don't need to `sort` the map if you just want to find the biggest value. You can instead use the [`reduce`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) method to iterate through each value in the list and determine which value you want to keep in the iteration:

```
void main() {
  final listOfMaps = [
    {'caseNumber': 1},
    {'caseNumber': 3},
    {'caseNumber': 2}
  ];

  final mapWithBiggestCaseNumber =
      listOfMaps.reduce((a, b) => a['caseNumber'] > b['caseNumber'] ? a : b);

  print(mapWithBiggestCaseNumber); // {caseNumber: 3}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use math library and reduce to check for the max value

```
import 'dart:math';

num biggest = _abcBloc.vpStream.value
     .map((abc) => abc.caseNumber).reduce(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class CustomObject {
  int value;

  CustomObject(this.value);
}

void main() {
  List<CustomObject> objects = [
    CustomObject(5),
    CustomObject(10),
    CustomObject(3),
    CustomObject(8),
  ];

  CustomObject maxObject = objects.reduce((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? a : b);
  print('The object with the biggest value is: ${maxObject.value}');
}
```

In this example, the CustomObject class has an int property named value. The reduce function is used on the objects list to compare the value property of each object and find the object with the biggest value. The resulting object is stored in the maxObject variable, and its value is printed.

Note that this example assumes the list is not empty. Additional checks should be added to handle empty lists if necessary.